# Showing that $\pi_n(X,v)$ satisfies inverse axiom.

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complex, higher-category-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

Given a fibrant simplicial set $X$ (has lifting condition with all horns) and a vertex $v \in X_0$.

> I want to show that the simplicial homotopy group $\pi_n(X,v)$ satisfies the inverse axiom. 
>   The composition law for two map $f,g:\Delta^n \rightarrow X$ is given in [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+homotopy+group).

I could show the identity axiom. Assuming associativity, it suffices to prove

> The left multiplication map 
>   $$ \pi_n(X,v) \rightarrow \pi_n(X,v), \quad [x] \mapsto [f][x] $$
>   is bijective.

This is stated in Goerss, simplicial homotopy theory. How does one show bijectivity?

Comment: Are you assuming that $X$ satisfies the Kan condition?

Comment: Sorry, $X$ is a fibrant simplicial set here.

Comment: For future visitors, since this had no answers, it's been asked again as part of another question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3780870/90543